# Looking for a CRM solution

Tags: evaluating-civicrm

: I am needing a quote. This will be for a political campaign that I serve as the IT Director. Needing software that allows integration of volunteers, their info, can send text or email, etc all from one place

Comment: What's the best option for implanting it

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange.  This is a question and answer forum so you won't get a quote here.  I would suggest that you contact a partner as Xavier suggests.  However, if you have a specific question about whether CiviCRM will meet your needs I suggest that you post this as a new question.  Try to be as detailed as possible about your requirements.

Comment: I will thank you

Comment: Hi we've done political campaigns for a number of years at JMA Consulting and @petednz at Fuzion has done a lot of work for Green Parties around the world. Best wishes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not good for Q&A format.

Comment: It may not fit the Q&A format but it's not 'off-topic' - it is about wanting a CRM for political campaigning which is very much 'on-topic' for CiviCRM.  We advertise SE as the place to ask questions - https://civicrm.org/ask-a-question.  A new user has come here looking for help and immediately having his question declared 'off-topic' will not encourage him to look at CiviCRM further.  Obviously he is not going to get a quote on two lines of info and needs to understand more about how the Civi community works, but we need a better way to redirect and nurture such interest.

Comment: The scope of what is 'on-topic' - http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic is very broad. Maybe we should add more info there, though I question how many new users read that before posting.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors and contact directly the providers that are in the country or provide the type of services you need